# Swift 3 selected button changing postition in collection view when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to make a collection view where each cell contains an image and a button that can each either be selected or not selected. Initially everything appears to work well, however after I press some buttons and move through the view some 'selected' buttons change to 'not selected' and vice versa.

I found that people have issues with images switching places so I have tried caching my images. I have also tried removing the images completely but the issue remains.

Here is my collection view setup:

```
override func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return imageArray.count

}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    //cell.photo.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.selectButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let length = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1


    return CGSize(width: length, height: length)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    //sets spacing between images
    return 1.0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    //sets spacing between images
    return 1.0
}
```

Here is my buttonPressed function:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.isSelected == true{
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for:UIControlState.normal)
        sender.isSelected = false
    }else{
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for:UIControlState.normal)
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to check the button condition each time while creating cell in `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

Take an **array** and keep all **selected indexes** in it.

```
 var mArray = [Int]()


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        //cell.photo.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.selectButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.selectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

//check if indexpath.row is selected
    if mArray.contains(indexPath.row){
                cell.selectButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for:UIControlState.normal)
                cell.selectButton.isSelected = true
    }else{
                cell.selectButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for:UIControlState.normal)
                cell.selectButton.isSelected = false
    }


        return cell

    }


func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.isSelected == true{
        mArray.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for:UIControlState.normal)
        sender.isSelected = false
    }else{
        mArray.append = sender.tag
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for:UIControlState.normal)
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I just revisited this and after more thorough testing it doesn't work. There was an issue caused by incorrect items being removed from the array which I fixed by swapping 'mArray.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)' to 'myArray = myArray.filter{ $0 != sender.tag }'. When I deselect items and quickly scroll the selected buttons switch positions, do you know what could be causing this?